# How to integrate a MAX and IF statement into a FOR loop in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to include an if statement into the MAX function and create a FOR loop in VBA.

What I want the code to do is to return the `MAX` value from column B into a new column when the value in column A equals the value in column I.  I also have more than 1,000 rows in the data set and so I need a loop.

Here is a screenshot of data set of the data set I'm working with:

[image: Screenshot of data set]

When I execute the following code (`max_no_loop`) on my data set, I get the output that I am looking for.  However, I want to loop over 1,000 rows and so I need `I2` to be changing with each step of the integration.

```
Sub max_no_loop()

  Range("K2").FormulaArray = "=MAX(IF(A:A=I2,B:B))"

End Sub
```

After thinking about it, I came up with the function below(`max_loop`) where I changed `I2` to `Cells(i, 9)`, however, when I run the function on my data, I get name errors (`#NAME?`) and don't get the desired outcome.

```
Sub max_loop():

Dim i As Integer

For i = 2 To 11
    Cells(i, 11).FormulaArray = "=MAX(IF(A:A=Cells(i, 9),B:B))"
Next i

End Sub
```

Why am I unable to make the function work when I integrate it into a for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pull out the variable part completely like below:

```
Sub max_loop():

Dim i As Integer

For i = 2 To 11
    Cells(i, 11).FormulaArray = "=MAX(IF(A:A=" & Cells(i, 9).Address & ",B:B))"
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: You can avoid instantiating a range object by using `= "=MAX(IF(A:A=I" & i & ",B:B))"` in this case. In theory this should also reduce the call stack size and thus make the code run faster

Comment: @TaylorScott Valid point. Code speed may not be of significance in this particular case though as it is dealing with 10 cells. I'd personally use `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` switch if speed was an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take your variable `i` outside the `"` of the formula.

Try the code below:

```
Sub max_loop():

Dim i As Integer

For i = 2 To 11
    Cells(i, 11).FormulaArray = "=MAX(IF(A:A=Cells(" & i & ", 9),B:B))"
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I pasted your code into my workbook and still got a name error.

Comment: It should be `Cells(i, 11).FormulaArray = "=MAX(IF(A:A=" & Cells(i, 9).Address & ",B:B))"`